# Send multiselected values from drowpdown to database (comma seperated) , now want to receive data as options again

Tags: php

I have a multi-select dropdown menu, getting data from DB as rows => options
when I select data to insert them to  another table in (one cell) it go as separated values (`val1`, `val2`, `val3`,..)
I want to get them back as rows in other dropdown menus 
I got `val1`, `val2`, `val3`,
I want to split this cell to options in the select menu

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KgWS.jpg)
Left options are new add 
right options are current selection (problem when loaded as comma)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa3Ey.jpg)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af1Oq.jpg)

explode, cross join

```
enter code here
<?php


$output = '';





if($_POST["action"] == 'tr_title')
{
    $empid = $_POST['empid'];

    $query = "SELECT tr_code FROM training WHERE tr_title = :tr_title";

    // query2 get train code from tbl_employee , Trying convert commas to options
    $query2 = "SELECT train_code  FROM tbl_employee WHERE id = '$empid' GROUP BY train_code"  ;

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':tr_title'     =>  $_POST["query"],

        )
    );

    $statement2 = $connect->prepare($query2);
    $statement2->execute();


    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $result2 = $statement2->fetchAll();


    foreach($result as $row)
    {


        $output .= '<option value="'.$row["tr_code"].'">'.$row["tr_code"].'</option>';
    }



    foreach($result2  as $row2)
     {

        $output2 .= '<option selected value="'.$row2["train_code"].'">'.$row2["train_code"].'</option>';
    }
}


echo $output,$output2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it ,

```
enter code here
```

```
$output = '';




if($_POST["action"] == 'tr_title')
{
    $empid = $_POST['empid'];

    $query = "SELECT tr_code FROM training WHERE tr_title = :tr_title";

    $query2 = "SELECT train_code  FROM tbl_employee WHERE id = '$empid' GROUP BY train_code"  ;

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':tr_title'     =>  $_POST["query"],

        )
    );

    $statement2 = $connect->prepare($query2);
    $statement2->execute();


    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $result2 = $statement2->fetchAll();


    // convert choices by comma separated to single choice


    foreach ($result2 as $row2){
    $getCode = $row2["train_code"];
    $splitCode = explode(",",$getCode);
}


    foreach($result as $row)
    {


        $output .= '<option value="'.$row["tr_code"].'">'.$row["tr_code"].'</option>';
    }



    foreach($splitCode  as $row3)
     {

        $output2 .= '<option selected value="'.$row3.'">'.$row3.'</option>';
    }
}


echo $output,$output2;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R2JB.png)